# Sketchup to Blender - Material not visible

Tags: modeling

So I have created a 3d model in sketchup and I have added material and texture to it..Now when I export it as .obj and open it in Blender, I can see the model but it is "naked"..I dont see any of my materials applied to it but I can still see the materials in the Materials tab..How to apply the materials on my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the add-on called **Blendup**. There are two versions: [free](http://sketchup2blender.com/blendup-get-started) and [paid](https://blendermarket.com/products/blendup-sketchup-to-blender-converter) ($35). The [free](http://sketchup2blender.com/blendup-get-started) version is limited to SketchUp models with less than 1000 faces.

Just install the add-on. Select your model in *File> Blendup*, select the settings you need and click *export*. Then open the blend file which you have exported from Sketchup and switch to *Material* or *Render* mode and you will see your material.

For more details watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjFoiEZpHts)

Comment: please help us on keeping the quality of this site. This question and answer site is accessed by lot of people who are non native english-speakers. Please make an extra effort and write the pronoun "you" instead of u, and avoid text-message language so that others can understand your answers better.