# Weird texture issues when importing Collada from SketchUp

Tags: collada

I'm relatively new to Blender and trying to import an architectural render from SketchUp 2017.

I export from SketchUp with Collada, then import, and end up with something like this:

[image: Import issues]

The meshes with problems do have two materials:

[image: Two materials set at the same time]

Putting the correct material on top helps some. Deleting the secondary material helps some of the time, but not all of the time.

Any ideas what this is? I've heard that importing from Collada can require hours of cleanup, but in this case am not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: look like Z fighting to me. See if there are any doubled up faces. That could be duplicate objects in the same spot, or duplicate faces in the same object.

Comment: Yup, that is not caused neither by materials nor textures, that loks like [Z-Fighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Z-Fighting) to me, which is cause by overlapping geometry or coinciding faces. That means it's cleanup time, and one of the reasons why Sketchup is such a clumsy modelling tool.

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70913/sketchup-to-blender-material-not-visible/70918#70918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! Yes, it was just normal Z-fighting (no pun intended).

Once I removed duplicate vertices, I could apply the textures and everything worked fine.